# Cloud Function in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

i have the Firebase as this:

```
Posts:
     <Unique-Key>
            Caption: "hello World"
            Time: "2017 Dec 17" 
            CurrentUserReaction: "false"
            UsersWhoReacted: 
                           <user-id> : 1
            image = "firebase....."
```

can somebody tell me what will be the firebase cloud function code to trigger CurrentUserReaction to "true" if the UserWhoReacted has the  of currently logged in user?

Answer (score 0):

There is an undocumented event.auth object that you can use to check the UID of the currently logged in user (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/133).

I haven't tested it but something along the lines of following code should acheive what you need:

```
exports.didCurrentUserReact = functions.database.ref('/posts/{postID}/UsersWhoReacted')
    .onUpdate(event => {
        // Get the user reaction object
        const userReactions = event.data.val();

        //Check if it no longer exists/deleted.
        if (!userReactions)
            return;

        //Get the current user id. This is undocumented object expected to me made available for use in a new form. Expect this code to break in the future.
        let currentUserUID = event.auth.uid;

        //Iterate over the keys and check if it matches the current user's id.
        let didCurrentUserReact = Object.keys(userReactions).some(id => {
            return (id === currentUserUID)
        });


        if (didCurrentUserReact)
            return event.data.ref.parent.child('CurrentUserReaction').set('true');


    });
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I solved the problem myself. Used different techniques. But, will surely look forward for your idea, if I am to add more flexibility ... THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: Cloud Functions are ( as stated in the name ) in the cloud ( meaning server-side ). They have nothing to do with the customer currently being logged in ( with respects to the current piece of code provided by you ). A database trigger has no clue who is the current ID, because it's not supposed to. The only auth context you can pass are to callable functions or https requests ( where you have to deal with the token validation yourself ).